# Leaking hot water tank connections

Tags: hot-water, brass-fitting

I modified the outlets on a solar hot water tank, and now it leaks.

The leak occurs between the brass fitting on the bottom (Edwards hot water) and the short pipe below. I don’t know what sort of connection it is.

If I don’t get any ideas, I will assume that the edwards fitting has an internal screw; and take everything apart to Teflon tape this.

This happened because I added another brass T piece for another hot water outlet.

[image]

Comment: Confused, is the picture now in right orientation

Comment: I have the text matching the current photo. I should explore photo orientation issues separately.

Comment: Give us the actual model number of the storage tank so we can look up the connection type

Comment: Did you move the Edwards fitting relative to the pipe underneath it? Where is the brass T that you added?

Comment: From the photo, it looks like the bottom of the pipe was badly bent.

Comment: This is a “before” picture, without the added T. The Edwards company has long been taken over by Rheem, and i could not find specifications on the internet. I fear I probably have rotated the lowest T slightly.